# How to upload multiple files/images when developing a wordpress plugin?

Tags: plugins, images

I decided to learn how to develop wordpress plugins and I am totally confused and frustrated. I've already read some good tutorials and I guess I am already familiar with the basics. Now, I want to start developing my first plugin and I decided to start with a javascript image slider. At this stage I know how to set up an admin page with all the settings I need (e.g. slider name, slider themes, which transitions to use, which pagination type etc..). I also know how to create a custom type for my slider, how to register scripts and styles, how to generate shortcodes and template tags etc..

What I am confused is how to go on with adding the images itself. I have seen some of the existing plugins but none seems to follow a common solution for this. In some one has to upload each image individually (the image being the post type itself), others use the wp file uploader but  only one image can get uploaded at a time etc.. The one I like the most is Nivo Slider, which adds the meta_box_upload with the plupload multiple file uploader script.

My question is, which options do I have here? Also, I can't seem to find any good tuts on this either (maybe cause of my lack of experience?). Any hints would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at: http://www.plupload.com/

This is the uploader that is used by WordPress in the admin area for media uploads.  You should be able to hook WordPress' version in to your plugin.